# Nakayama lemma (local algebra- Jean Pierre Serre)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am seeing Jean Pierre Serre's book entitled "local algebra."

At the beginning of chapter 1 they state the motto of Nakayama. I will change some notations and place what the book says

Proposition 1. Let $M$  be a finitely generated $A$ -module, and $I$ be
an ideal of $A$ contained in the  Jacobson radical $J$ of $A$.  If $IM = M$ , then $M =0$ .

Proof:

Indeed, if $M\neq 0$ , it has a quotient which is a simple module (because if $M$ is finely generated then there is a submodule $N$ of $M$ such that the quotient $M/N$ is simple), hence
is isomorphic to $A/m$, where $m$ is a maximal ideal of $A$; then $mM\neq M$ ,
contrary to the fact that $I\subset J$.

Why $mM\neq M$ ?

Comment: $M/N \cong A/m$ as $A$-modules means $mM\subset N$ and $N\subsetneq M$ because $A/m$ is non-trivial. Finally $IM\subset mM \subsetneq M$.